# Bootstrap datepicker 1.6.4

Tags: php, jquery, html5, bootstrap-datepicker

quero saber como eu faço pra iniciar a data habilitada para o dia de amanhã no datepicker bootstrap, por exemplo, o usuário não pode selecionar a data de hoje e nem de ontem, o usuário só pode clicar em datas apartir de amanhã em ate 3 dias úteis, não podendo clicar aos domingos também.

Segue meu código:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        language: "pt-BR",
        minViewMode: 0,
        orientation: 'auto',
        startDate: "date",
        autoclose: true,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: ['0']
    });
```

Alguém se habilita para resolver este problema?

Answer (score 1):

Altere a propriedade `startDate` de:

```
startDate: "date",
```

para:

```
startDate: '+1d',
```

Segue abaixo exemplo funcional:

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    language: "pt-BR",
    minViewMode: 0,
    orientation: 'auto',
    startDate: '+1d',
    autoclose: true,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: ['0']
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.min.js"></script>




<input type="text" name="myDatepicker" value = "" class="datepicker" />
```

Espero ter ajudado!